# Have compiler warn if a function is used

Tags: c, macros, warnings, c-preprocessor

I have **C** code with lots of calls `strcmp` and `strcpy` that is causing all kinds of problems.
I want to migrate this to `strncmp` and `strncpy` but I can not update all the code right now. I want to add compiler warning where ever the functions is used.

The following forces the substitution `#define strcmp(x,y) strncmp16(x,y,64)` but the problem is still in the code.

Is there a way to add an `#warning` so that the code still compile but will give a warning for not using the sized functions.

It is a large code base and must compile in four different compilers (GCC, IAR, GHS and VC). It is our own **C** Library mainly used in embedded systems.

**Edit:** I am not looking to find all occurrences. There is thousands of tools that can be used to find and replace them. I want there to be a warning so the next time somebody looks at the code they would evaluate and fix the code.

**Edit:** Strncmp & strncpy have lots of issues and I am very aware of that. I am making an informed decision. These function is in our own **C** library not just the default functions from the compilers **C** library.

Comment: Why are you not using find and replace feature of your editor (if there is) ?

Comment: It is a large code base. All changes must be evaluated induvidually. Instead of going for a single big bang I want to phase the changes in over a month or two.

Comment: @gerhard, still find where they are used using your editor (or grep) and look at them individually. It's easier (and more efficient) to search the files than compile them and have the compiler tell you where they are used!!

Comment: Doing this with preprocessor *is* find/replace done in single big bang. What Shahbaz is suggesting is a lot safer alternative. Also don't even consider using `strncpy`. You would only trade one set of problems to another, more subtle (and dangerous) set of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can use #define to force errors, there is no mechanism in the C99 standard (and probably none in C11 either) to force a warning.

If you are using gcc, you can use

```
__attribute_deprecated__
```

to mark a prototype as deprecated, e.g.:

```
int strcmp(const char *, const char *) __attribute_deprecated__;
```

Comment: I've seen `__attribute__((deprecated))` and `__attribute__((deprecated("message")))` as well. the latter has the advantage of adding a message, but do you happen to know the differences between the message-free versions with double parentheses and the one without double parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio:
prefix the function prototype with __declspec(deprecated) as seen in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/044swk7y%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

You'll need to raise the warning level to 3+.

Example:

```
#pragma deprecated(strcpy, strcmp)
```

This line will cause every call to either function to omit a C4995 warning.
These specific functions already emit a C4996 warning but you turn that warning off via a pragma:
    #pragma warning(disable: 4996)